# Modify timeseries data individual values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, time-series

Going a bit crazy here as I am not managing to use the index referencing for my newly-created timeseries objects.

All I wish to do is query/return/modify the value from a particular date.

i.e. where my timeseries "temp" is daily values for temperature and I want to change the value on January 16th 2008.
My date structure is formatted as such "01-Jan-2008"

I have tried various ways, but not managing! :(

```
temp('16-Jan-2008')= 25; % Info on this page ref [1]
temp(16) = 25; % 16 referring to the element index
```

I know that I could go into tstools and modify it manually, but I want to do much further matrix manipulation with the timeseries but am struggling somehow even with the index referencing! Can they not be modified easily in the command window?

Thanks

[1] - http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/finance/working-with-financial-time-series-objects.html#f13-5213

Comment: I think you want something like `temp.MySeriesName(16) = 25`

Comment: Thanks! This has helped to some extent, although I think there are other issues I need to address with my data - cheers for the pointer

Comment: @Dan I recommend you to post it as an answer so the question won't remain open.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 vectors

time [size = n by 1] & temp [size = n by 1]

If ur timeseries is a char vector (all rows same length and not cell). U can convert to matlab time nums like

```
time_tmp = datenum(time,'dd-mmm-yyyy');
```

Then u can change a temp vector (same length as time)

```
temp(time_tmp == datenum(2008,1,16)) = 25;
```

otherwise u can convert ur data to 2 vectors then do above.